# Switching between kernel versions in raspberry pi 4

Tags: boot, kernel, config.txt

My rpi4 is currently loading kernel `6.1.14-v7l+` at boot, while I have more installed:

```
$ ls /lib/modules
5.15.84+  5.15.84-v7+  5.15.84-v7l+  5.15.84-v8+  6.1.14+  6.1.14-v7+  6.1.14-v7l+  6.1.14-v8+  6.1.19+  6.1.19-v7+  6.1.19-v7l+
```

How can I switch to, for instance, `6.1.19-v7l+` or `5.15.84+`?

Do I just need to add a line to `/boot/config.txt`? Shouldn't I run some other command that puts the right files into `/boot`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run rpi-update?

Comment: You need to direct `rpi-update` to store the kernel in a different folder (under `/boot`) then point to that with `config.txt`. It's unusual to require that and not recommended. Just delete the uneeded folders and stick with 6.1.14.

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that all those module directories have been left around; `apt` usually removes them when a new kernel is installed.

RpiOS implements the unusual (GNU/Linux wise) policy of replacing kernels on update rather than leaving at least the previous one around in case there's a problem with the new one; this is perhaps justified on the basis of the platform being very hardware specific (and the new kernel has already been tested on exactly that hardware).

Anyway, you can't actually run those kernels because there's only one for each architecture in `/boot` (`kernel.img`, `kernel7.img`,`kernel8.img`, etc.), and that's the file that gets replaced; in your case `kernel7l.img` is v6.1.14-v7l+.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I needed to run a certain kernel version only because I wanted to compile a driver and I only had kernel headers for some kernel versions and not for the one the machine was running. Anyway, I abandoned the idea after your post :)